# Using QPainter::CompositionMode with multiple overlapping QGraphicsItems

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene, qpainter

I have a `QGraphicsScene` with several `MyQGraphicsItems`, which I subclassed from `QGraphicsItem`, inside of it. Inside the `paint` event of `MyQGraphicsItem`, I have

```
painter->drawImage(image_rect, m_image);
```

so every `MyQGraphicsItem` presents a `QImage` to the user. `m_image` is simply a `QImage` that supports an alpha channel:

```
m_image = image.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
```

The user can drag these items around such that regions of **two or more** items may overlap at any time.  Whenever two or more `MyQGraphicsItems` overlap, I want to set the transparency of the overlapping region such that all the items are equally visible in that region (but the non-overlapping regions should remain opaque).

Currently, I have to compute the overlap manually, and then use `painter->setOpacity(opacity);`.  This is inconvenient and difficult.  After searching the internet I feel that using [`QPainter::CompositionMode`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qpainter.html#CompositionMode-enum) is the correct way to go, but I have no idea how to use this.

I looked at [this example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwidgets-painting-composition-example.html), but my case is different in the sense that I have completely separate items that are overlapping, and thus I cannot paint them all with a single `QPainter`.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.